# How to find similar tags from text using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, text-mining

I try to use `Elastic Search` to find most similar tags from text.

For example, I create test_index and insert two documents:

```
POST test_index/_doc/17
{
  "id": 17,
  "tags": ["it", "devops", "server"]
}

POST test_index/_doc/20
{
  "id": 20,
  "tags": ["software", "hardware"]
}
```

So, i expect to find "**software**" tag (text or id) from "**I'm using some softwares and applications**" text.

I was hoping someone can provide an example on how to do this or at least point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is nothing but a concept called as [`Stemming`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming). You would need to create a [Custom Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) and make use of [Stemmer Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html).

Please find the below mapping, sample documents, query and response:

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_stem_index
{
  "settings": {
      "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
              "my_analyzer" : {
                  "tokenizer" : "standard",
                  "filter" : ["lowercase", "my_stemmer"]
              }
          },
          "filter" : {
              "my_stemmer" : {
                  "type" : "stemmer",
                  "name" : "english"
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "tags":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword":{
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From comments, it appears that you are using version < 7. For that you may have to add `type` in it.

```
PUT my_stem_index
{
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "analyzer":{
            "my_analyzer":{
               "tokenizer":"standard",
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase",
                  "my_stemmer"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "my_stemmer":{
               "type":"stemmer",
               "name":"english"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "_doc":{
         "properties":{
            "id":{
               "type":"keyword"
            },
            "tags":{
               "type":"text",
               "analyzer":"my_analyzer",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST my_stem_index/_doc/17
{
  "id": 17,
  "tags": ["it", "devops", "server"]
}

POST my_stem_index/_doc/20
{
  "id": 20,
  "tags": ["software", "hardware"]
}

POST my_stem_index/_doc/21
{
  "id": 21,
  "tags": ["softwares and applications", "hardwares and storage devices"]
}
```

### Request Query:

```
POST my_stem_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "tags": "software"
    }
  }
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.5908618,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_stem_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "20",
        "_score" : 0.5908618,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 20,
          "tags" : [
            "software",
            "hardware"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_stem_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "21",
        "_score" : 0.35965496,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 21,
          "tags" : [
            "softwares and applications",             <--- Note this has how `softwares` also was searchable.
            "hardwares and storage devices"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice in response as how both the documents i.e. having `_id 20` and `21` appear.

### Additional Note:

If you are new to Elasticsearch, I'd suggest spending sometime to understand the concept of [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and how Elasticsearch implements the same using [`Analyzers`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html).

This would help you understand how the document with `softwares and applications` is also returning when you only query for `software` and or vice versa.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it, even default analyzer `stanard` also created a token `software` for text **software**, then why to use stemming token, its not a stemmed text. I think question from OP is not clear.

Comment: @es-enthu If you notice carefully, he wants documents having `softwares`(plural) to be returned even if he searches for `software` (singular). Another example is if he searches for word `wait`, he should get documents having `waiting, waited` etc to also be returned. I think that is what OP is looking for.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal your mapping setting doesn't work, it has problem, reason": "Failed to parse mapping [properties]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [id : {type=keyword}] [tags : {analyzer=my_analyzer, type=text, fields={keyword={type=keyword}}}], i'm using 6.8 version.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal i find problem reason, you don't write document type "_doc" after mappings, please edit yout answer. thank you

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal How about, i find "soft ware" text, but return anything. what am i doing? it seems, `stemming` is not good way, i think, `Ngram` is better way.

Comment: @alireza Yes, I initially thought of using `Ngrams` but wasn't sure you'd need it based on the question details you've posted. You may want to take into consideration the index size if you want to implement `Ngram`. Normally if your use case is `soft ware` best to use ngrams tokenizer.

Comment: @alireza I've tested the solution on 7.6 ES version. Post version 7, `type` has been deprecated and hence the default type would be `_doc`. Please put all these details in any question you ask next time, so it would be easy for us to give you answer. Regardless, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @alireza Let me know if you need any help on implementing `Ngram`, I can update my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

If you search text that has base or root word, `Stemming` is good way.

If you need to find most similar word(s) from text, `Ngram` is more suitable way.

If you search exact words of text in word of tags, `Shingles` is better way.